# How to use jQuery variable in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I use the value stored in var height, as value on for margin-top?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var height = $(window).height() / 2;

      $("a").click(function(){

        $("#loader").css({"margin-top:", ***height});

      });

    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Removing the `***`?

Comment: just remove ***...otherwise your code is correct

Comment: You might have a problem with the `position` too : you can't set margin-top on any block.

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var height = $(window).height() / 2;

      $("a").click(function(){

        $("#loader").css('margin-top', height+'px');

      });

    });
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MtEjP/

Comment: The *** is just to show where height is used. But it don't work. my editor don't like this syntax :(

Comment: remove *** and set as a comment, otherwise......

Comment: I've added a demo in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#loader").css('margin-top', height+'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `:` and put outside before var `height` and `***`:

```
$("#loader").css({"margin-top" : height});
```

This one can be used to set multiple css attributes and properties:

```
$("selector").css({"cssattribute" : "cssproperty", 
                   "cssattribute" : "cssproperty"});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to set marginTop

```
  $('#loader').css('marginTop', height);
```

check demo here ..... http://jsfiddle.net/SUBqf/

Answer (score 0):

you can write that with 2 ways:

```
$("#loader").css({"margin-top": height});
```

or

```
$("#loader").css("margin-top", height);
```

You must select first way with multi attr usage. And seperate them with *comma* (,).

```
Ex: $("#loader").css({"margin-top": height, "margin-bottom": height, "margin-left": "10px"});
```